# How can I delete a file from an ftp server using a java program that are N weeks old

Tags: java, apache, delete-file, ftp-client, ftps

Our server is Unix server. Using jdk 1.7 and I am looking for a solution to delete files on the ftp server that are N weeks old.

Found  Apache FTPClient example but this not using date to delete files:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(host, port);
client.login(loginname, password);
client.deleteFile(fileNameOnServer);
client.disconnect();
```

I need example of how to delete files on ftp server based on date (like all file 3 weeks back).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824983/get-latest-file-from-ftp asnwer can be found here....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocodish.  You will have to settle on files that haven't beed modified in three weeks via FTPClient interface

for (FTPFile f : client.listFiles()) {
    Long t = f.getTimeStamp();
    if t is more than three weeks ago
       delete f
}