# Make FTP server return files listed by timestamp with Apache FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have written this below code to connect to a remote FTP Server (vsftp in CentOS 6). (For brevity Exception handling is not shown here)

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(20000);
ftpClient.connect(serverip);
ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftpClient.login(username, password);

if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
    ftpClient.disconnect();
    throw new FTPConnectionClosedException("Unable to connect to FTP server...");
}

FTPFile[] filesList = ftpClient.listFiles();
for (FTPFile tmpFile : filesList) {
    if (tmpFile.isDirectory())
        continue;

    // processing the file
}

if (ftpClient.isConnected())
    ftpClient.disconnect();
```

If there are 100 files in that FTP server, this `listFiles()` gives the list of file names according to the Alphabetical order.

```
A.txt
B.txt
Z.txt
a.txt
z.txt
```

**Is there any way to get the files according to the modified time?** (i.e. oldest files first). This `listFiles()` uses `LIST` command. **Is there any other command available to list the files according to the modification time.? Since this is a Linux server, can we send some Linux commands to achieve this?**

I have already checked question [get latest file from ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3824983/850848). The problem with this approach is that we have to order the files using a `Comparator` then rename and move it a different folder (To get them in the modification order). If there are more than 1000 files, sorting them would become a time consuming operation!

Edit:
And more over, retrieving the files and sorting them has another problem. It doesn't have `seconds` information when `ftpFile.getTimestamp()` is used. It is accurate only to minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no standard way to have the FTP server sort the files according to your (or any) criteria.

Though some FTP servers, notably the ProFTPD and vsftpd, support proprietary flags with the `LIST` command to sort the entries.

Both these servers support the `-t` flag to sort the files by a modification time:

```
LIST -t
```

Though this is not only non-standard, it actually violates the FTP protocol.

For all options supported by ProFTPD, see its man page:
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/ListOptions.html

Note that vsftpd supports only `-a`, `-r`, `-t`, `-F` and `-l` with the same meaning as ProFTPD.

The Apache Commons Net has no API to add flags to the `LIST` command (the only exception, while irrelevant to this question, is the `-a` flag – which is sent when `FTPClient.setListHiddenFiles` is set).

You would have to override the [`FTPClient.getListArguments`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getListArguments(java.lang.String)) to inject your own flags.

---

Though again, I do not see what's wrong with using [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to sort the files. Just make sure you use [`FTPClient.mlistDir()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#mlistDir()), which internally uses a modern `MLSD` command. This way you get precise timestamps, not minute- or worse precision timestamps like with obsolete `LIST` - [`FTPClient.listFiles()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()).

```
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.mlistDir(remotePath);
        
Arrays.sort(remoteFiles,
    Comparator.comparing((FTPFile remoteFile) -> remoteFile.getTimestamp())
        .reversed());
```

Though, as you commented, the vsftpd does not support `MLSD` (ProFTPD does). In that case the `LIST -t` is indeed the only efficient (although again, not standard/portable) way to get precisely sorted files. Except for a time-consuming call of `MDTM` – [`FTPClient.getModificationTime`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getModificationTime(java.lang.String)) for each listed file. If you can do without precise timestamps, the same code as above, but with `FTPClient.listFiles()` will do.

See also [Fetching last modified date of a file in FTP server using FTPClient.getModificationTime yields null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49623415/850848).