# Fetching last modified date of a file in FTP server using FTPClient.getModificationTime yields null

Tags: java, ftp, timestamp, apache-commons-net

I am trying to fetch last modified date of a file from FTP environment.The result is not as expected.

By using `ftpClient.getModificationTime("File path")` I am getting **null**.

By using `FTPFile.getTimestamp().getTime()` I am getting **wrong last modified** (i.e. real last modified is of today and I am getting *Wed Feb 18 02:55:22 EST 2004*).

How to get correct last modified?

[image: File at FTP]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FTPClient.getModificationTime`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#getModificationTime(java.lang.String)) returns `null` when the server returns an error response to `MDTM` command. Typically that would mean either that:

- *"File path"* does not exists; or
- the FTP server does not support `MDTM` command.

Check [`FTPClient.getReplyString()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#getReplyString()).

---

If it turns out that the FTP server does not support `MDTM` command, you will have to use another method to retrieve the timestamps. If `MDTM` is not supported, `MLSD` won't be either.

In that case the only other way is using `LIST` command to retrieve listing of all files and lookup the file you need - Use [`FTPClient.listFiles()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles()).

```
FTPFile[] remoteFiles = ftpClient.listFiles(remotePath);

Arrays.sort(remoteFiles,
    Comparator.comparing((FTPFile remoteFile) -> remoteFile.getTimestamp()).reversed());

FTPFile latestFile = remoteFiles[0];
System.out.println(
    "Latest file is " + latestFile.getName() +
    " with timestamp " + latestFile.getTimestamp().getTime().toString());
```

See also [Make FTP server return files listed by timestamp with Apache FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36032064/850848).