# Is there a way in talend to find the files from the last 24 hours or within 1 day without reading through entire file list from ftp

Tags: java, date, ftp, components, talend

The ftp folder has around 4000-5k files present there and i dont want to be passing them into a bufferinput/output component and after that sort them using tmap function .Instead i would prefer without bothering the no.of files in the ftp folder directly can i find the files from last day(24 hours timeframe) and use ftpget?

I dont want to go through the hassle of storing/reading all the files in a bufferedreader and sort/arrange by mtime_desc or by other ftpfileproperties method.Instead a direct way to fetch and retrieve the most recent files from previous day would be quite faster and effective?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Talend, but: The standard FTP can retrieve only all files in the directory. No optimization or filtering possible, no matter what language/library/framework you are using.

*Some* FTP servers support a non-standard `LIST -t` command to retrieve the listing sorted by timestamp. When you use that, you may break a download of the listing, once you get the files you need.  See also [Make FTP server return files listed by timestamp with Apache FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36032064/850848).

Comment: Thanks for your response,so you're saying there is no way to filter and directly pull only the latest files from a ftp folder without reading through all the files in the folder and then only perform the sort based on latest timestamp.If that is the case,i am doing the same i am observing performance hit drastically,i was wondering if there is anyway to make if efficient by directly pulling the latest files from past 24 hours without reading all the files in that folder!Which would surely increase the processing speed/time

Comment: As I wrote, some servers support the `-t` switch, which could help you.