# How to download chosen file from ftp-server using java?

Tags: java, ftp

I need to choose last file from FTP server and download it.
i can chose file, but can not download it.
How i can do it?

my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String server = "ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us";
    int port = 21;
    String username = "anonymous";
    String password = "ftp.swfwmd.state.fl.us";
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    client.connect(server);
    client.login(username, password);
    FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
    
    // how to download this file?
    FTPFile lastFile = lastFileModified(files);
    client.disconnect();
}

public static FTPFile lastFileModified(FTPFile[] files) {
    Date lastMod = files[0].getTimestamp().getTime();
    FTPFile choice = files[0];
    for (FTPFile file : files) {
        if (file.getTimestamp().getTime().after(lastMod)) {
            choice = file;
            lastMod = file.getTimestamp().getTime();
            System.out.println("DOWNLOAD TIME: " + file.getTimestamp().getTime() + "\nFILE NAME:  " + file.getName());

        }
    }
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: well you may try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824983/get-latest-file-from-ftp

Comment: code is choosing file, but not download.